# Call one function from another function in PHP class

Tags: php, class, function, oop

I want to scan directories and subdirectories, make list of xml files, take content from xml files and display it. This functions work correctly without OOP. I try to create a class. I call function `scandir_through` from function `main`. I haven't errors, result too.

```
class data {
    var $dir = 'D:\wamp4\www\begin';

    public function scandir_through($dir)
     {
         $items = glob($dir . '/*');
         for ($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
             if (is_dir($items[$i])) {
                 $add = glob($items[$i] . '/*');
                 $items = array_merge($items, $add);
             }
         }
        return $items;
     }

    public function main()
    {
        $scan_tree = $this->scandir_through($dir);
        echo "<ul id='booklist'>"."</n>";
        foreach ($scan_tree as $key=>$file){
            $url = $file;
            $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);  
               $book_count = count($xml->book); 
               for($i = 0; $i < $book_count; $i++) { 
                   $book = $xml->book[$i]; 
                   $title=$xml->book[$i]->title;
                   $author=$xml->book[$i]->author;
                   //echo '</br>';
                   //echo $file. " &nbsp   ";
                   //echo $title. " &nbsp   ";
                   //echo $author;
                   echo "<li><div class='file'>".$file."</div>
                   <div class='title'>".$title."</div>
                   <div class='author'>".$author."</div></li></n>";
               }     
         }  
          echo "</ul>";
    }
}
$d = new data();
$d->main();
?>
```

Comment: Please remember that PHP is a multi-paradigm language. You don't **need** to use OOP everywhere.

Comment: No, my mystake, incorrect copy.

Comment: OOP is need for this task.

Comment: kindly provide the output of $items

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is because the `$dir` instance variable isn't what you're accessing within your main method. (It's looking for a `$dir` variable in the scope of that method, rather than at the class level.)

What you need to use is...

```
$scan_tree = $this->scandir_through($this->dir);
```

If you turn on E_NOTICE warnings, you'll see that it'll have been throwing an error.

Comment: I was tryed this, but I have a blank page, no result.

Answer (score 3):

I think that $dir should be an argument for main. Just think if you had nothing else in the class, where would main get $dir from?

I would change:

```
public function main()
```

to

```
public function main($dir)
```

and when you call main using $d, include the dir so change that to:

```
$d->main($dir);
```

Comment: @vili if $d->main($dir) doesn't work try it without since you already have the $dir in the class.

Answer (score 1):

```
$items=data::scandir_through($dir);
```